# mapping of list with that particular data in the list

Tags: php, html, foreach

I am trying to display a gallery page, where there are different tabbed list i.e Gallery Name which is being fetched from the database. Each of these is mapped with `data-list-id` 
Now each gallery has a particular set of images in it. 
The list looks like: 
ALL 
List 1 
List 2 
List 3 
Here's the HTML that would display the content of these List:

```
<div class="full-gallery details-area">
    <div class="gallery-1 gallery-all">
        <a href="img/img1.jpg" data-ngthumb="img/img1.jpg">image1</a>
        <a href="img/img1.jpg" data-ngthumb="img/img1.jpg">image1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The same is implemented with change in `gallery-1` to `gallery-2` , `gallery-3` which will map with the respective List.

Now my job is to make it dynamic. I get the results but with a slight bug. 
This is what I did in PHP:

```
<?php
$gallery_index=1;
$id=$SITE['site_settings']->cloud_site_id;
$gal="SELECT gallery_id, gallery_image_url from `cloud_site_gallery_images` where `cloud_site_id`= $id and gallery_image_status=1;";

$res = $DB->query($gal);
uasort($res,'cmp_by_gallery');?>
<?php 
$test=0;
$temp=array();
$temp[0]=$res[0]->gallery_id; ?>
<div class="full-gallery details-area">
    <?php
    foreach($res as $galleryList)
    { 
        if($temp[$test] != $galleryList->gallery_id)
        $gallery_index++;
    ?>
        <div class="gallery-<?php echo $gallery_index; ?> gallery-all"> <br>
        <a href="<?php echo WWW_GALLERY_IMAGE_PATH.'original/'.$galleryList->gallery_image_url; ?>" rel= "<?php echo $galleryList->gallery_id; ?>" data-ngthumb="<?php echo WWW_GALLERY_IMAGE_PATH.'original/'.$galleryList->gallery_image_url; ?>">image1</a>
                <?php 
                $temp[++$test]=$galleryList->gallery_id; 
                ?>
        </div>
        <?php 

    } ?>
```

The result that I get with this is not the same as that in HTML. While the `$gallery_index` is 1, it should print all the images in the `gallery-1` and then it should increment to 2.

`<div class="gallery-1 gallery-all nanogallery_theme_light nanogallery_thumbnails_label_align_center unselectable">`

`</div>`
This is what I should get. Here all the images are clubbed into this `class=gallery-1` 
But I get something like this:

`<div class="gallery-1 gallery-all nanogallery_theme_light nanogallery_thumbnails_label_align_center">` `</div>` 
`<div class="gallery-1 gallery-all nanogallery_theme_light nanogallery_thumbnails_label_align_center">` `</div>`

Here every image comes as different `div` 
I am not able to figure out the exact problem

EDIT:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [gallery_id] => 28
    [gallery_image_url] => Hydrangeas+1416289924.jpg
)


 stdClass Object ( [gallery_id] => 28 [gallery_image_url] => Main+Qimg+D3344dabee4d48e5ee08eabff738f5dd+1416211112.png ) stdClass Object ( [gallery_id] => 28 [gallery_image_url] => Main+Qimg+A17a77318cc563cb43ae387170c79b75+1416211067.jpg ) stdClass Object ( [gallery_id] => 61 [gallery_image_url] => Img2+1416221089.jpg ) stdClass Object ( [gallery_id] => 61 [gallery_image_url] => Img1+1416221043.jpg ) stdClass Object ( [gallery_id] => 62 [gallery_image_url] => Koala+1416293951.jpg ) stdClass Object ( [gallery_id] => 62 [gallery_image_url] => Chrysanthemum+1416293916.jpg ) stdClass Object ( [gallery_id] => 62 [gallery_image_url] => Desert+1416288139.jpg ) stdClass Object ( [gallery_id] => 62 [gallery_image_url] => Lighthouse+1416293790.jpg ) stdClass Object ( [gallery_id] => 62 [gallery_image_url] => Tulips+1416293867.jpg )
```

Comment: `I get the results but with a slight bug.`. What's the bug?

Comment: @S.Pols Edited the question. Sorry, that was mistake.

Comment: Think about first just collect your gallery items into an array, and then loop through on that, not directly from the result of your query. More easy to access the first element, and maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, this code will create a seperate div for each image.
You need to put the div declaration out of the foreach loop. Try this:

```
<?php

    $galleries = array();
    foreach($res as $galleryImage)
    {
        $galleries[$galleryImage->gallery_id][] = $galleryImage->->gallery_image_url;
    }

    foreach($galleries as $galleryId => $galleryImages)
    {    
        $gallery_index++;
?>
        <div class="gallery-<?php echo $gallery_index; ?> gallery-all"> <br>
            <?php
                foreach($galleryImages as $image)
                { 
            ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo WWW_GALLERY_IMAGE_PATH.'original/'.$image; ?>" rel= "<?php echo $galleryId; ?>" data-ngthumb="<?php echo WWW_GALLERY_IMAGE_PATH.'original/'.$image; ?>">image1</a>
            <?php 
                }
            ?>
        </div>
<?php
    } 
?>
```

Comment: This code displays only 1st gallery i.e `gallery-1`. The `$gallery_index` is not being incremented. And in addition to it, it prints all the images from all galleries.

Comment: True, you need to place another foreach loop in the current foreach loop. In this loop you can loop throught the images in `galleryList`. I don't know how `$galleryList` is look like.

Comment: Ok and where would that second foreach loop will be?? Inside the current foreach, but what will it loop?? `<a href>` ??

Comment: Can you give a dump of print_r of `$galleryList`?

Comment: Edited my answer. Try this.

Comment: Nope. This doesn't work too. Instead, it prints 10 galleries. And I have 10 images from all the 3 galleries.

Comment: `$galleryList` is the gallery right? And inside `$galleryList` there are images. So first loops through the galleries and the second loop through the image. If this doesn't work. The data is not what you expect. Can you else provide a print_r of `$res`?

Comment: The print_r is provided in the question. Yes $galleryList contains all the details of the galleries but not just one particular gallery, like `gallery_id`, `gallery_image_url` and many more, but the rest of the data is irrelevant. When I debug `$image`, I only get the ID of a gallery

Comment: Think i understand the problem now, let's give it another try. Updated my answer again

Comment: It works perfect! Except that the loop starts from 2 and not from 1, so my List-1 gets empty.

Comment: Good, almost there! Just change `$gallery_index=1;` to `$gallery_index=0;`. That will do the job.

Comment: I need to come to your place and give you a big treat! Thanks a lot for all the time that you took out.